# Run files under /usr/sbin using exec

Tags: c, exec, fork

I want to run a file under /usr/sbin using execvp with argument(another file) in C.

For example : /usr/sbin/abc /Desktop/abc.txt -> this command is typed in terminal. However I want to run the command using C.

I tried execvp("/usr/sbin/abc", "/usr/sbin/abc" , "/Desktop/abc.txt"); but this gives me delimeters error.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Read the documentation for `execvp` more carefully.

Comment: `execv()` is not the same as `execl()`.

Answer (score 1):

All of the functions in the `exec` family with a `v` in them take an array of arguments. The function you're trying to use here is `execl()`, and it needs a `NULL` argument at the end:

```
execl("/usr/sbin/abc", "/usr/sbin/abc" , "/Desktop/abc.txt", NULL);
```

Comment: The terminating parameter shall be `(char *) NULL`.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. While there are some obscure crazy systems on which not all pointers are the same, I don't think any of them have `execl()`.